# Issue with application after creating Setup

Tags: wpf, windows

I have a application in which if any popup (window) raise at minimize state on click of window icon at T
Taskbar Maximizes both popup and main window, this works fine with release and debug mode, after creating installer this feature does not work.

I am using:

.net framework 4.6.1
Visual Studio 2015
WPF application
Visual Studio 2010 installer(setup) patch

Comment: You can use https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ to debug installed WPF application.

Comment: The Scoop thing dint worked for me.. If I copy paste my code in some other drive like D, the code works fine, if I put in the C:ProgramFiles, it is not working, I have full admin permission for the C drive as well as for Program files folder.

Comment: Nobody will give you further help without any code samples, I'm afraid.